# abnormal program termination turbo c

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to run an combined code of C that calling assembly procedure, and I get abnormal program termination message.
Its very simple code, the assembly procedure scans a number and return the result to c.

```
;main code
#include<stdio.h>
extern long getPnum();
int main()
{
    long x;
    x = getPnum();
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}


;getPNum
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
NUM DD 0

.CODE
.386
PUBLIC _getPnum
_getPnum PROC NEAR

PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP
PUSH EAX
PUSH EBX
PUSH ECX
MOV EBX,10

SCAN:
        MOV EAX,NUM
        MUL EBX
        MOV ECX,EAX
        XOR EAX,EAX
        MOV AH,1
        INT 21H
        CMP AL,13
        JE NEXT
        SUB AL,'0'
        MOV AH,0
        ADD ECX,EAX
        MOV NUM,ECX
        JMP SCAN
NEXT:
MOV AX,WORD PTR NUM
MOV DX,WORD PTR NUM+2
ADD SP,14
RET
_getPnum ENDP
END
```

---

I changed the `%d` to `ld%`, and now I get another error: `Dimdie error`
It's very strange when I run the DEBUGER I return the number through AX DX,and X gets the wrong value 
[debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Y7k.jpg)
[result scrren](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvP8P.jpg)

---

I Changed

```
ADD SP,14
RET
```

to

```
ADD SP,12
POP BP
RET
```

and now I don't get any errors, but the printed value is incorrect, despite that the returned value trough DX:AX is correct

Comment: Any change to attach a debugger?

Comment: Why is code using `"%d"` to print a `long` instead of `"%ld"`?  A good compiler with warnings fully enabled would save you time and warn about this.  Perhaps with "warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long int'".  Does this fix things for you?

Comment: @chux i tried it didn't help

Comment: @chux: OP uses TurboC, which should answer the question about a good compiler. OP. TurboC is outdated since more than 20 years. It is not standard compliant since 19 years now and should not be used. It also does not support modern computer platforms. Use a modern toolchain like gcc or clang. And don't use assembler code if not necessary. Said that: what do you want to achieve? What is the problem you try to solve with that code?

Comment: @toohonest This is what we are allowed to use in school.
And the task is to check if a number is proth using 5 Assembly procedures

Comment: Find a better school. Writing such code (or the one TC supports) will give you a serious talk with your boss in every reasonable team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BP` **must** be restored when you leave the procedure.

Change

```
ADD SP,14
RET
```

to

```
ADD SP,12
POP BP
RET
```

Better is:

```
MOV SP, BP
POP BP
RET
```

BTW: Why do you push a bunch of registers which you don't restore at the end of the function?

Comment: Yes you're right, I changed it but it still did not help, it prints an incorrect value even though the value returned through DX: AX is right, X gets the wrong value.
And I push all these registers because it's one procedure out of a many and I do not know if I'll use these registers ...

Comment: @DanielYachnev: No error here. What does your console input look like? To print a LONG you have to change `printf("%d", x);` to `printf("%ld", x);`

Comment: yes i already  changed it.X gets wrong value,despite that the returned value trough DX:AX is correct

Comment: @DanielYachnev: I'm sorry, I cannot produce a wrong value here with the code you've posted. (tried a lot). Try first to delete all .EXE and .OBJ files when you start a new compile run. Try to restore at least `EBX` when you leave the procedure.